# Setting Firefox preferences using policies.json

Tags: firefox

Scenario:  A custom(legacy) app depends on Firefox on Windows.  The following Firefox preferences are manually configured at install:[default]

```
  modify: "dom.popup_maximum": [20] 500,
  modify: "browser.cache.check_doc_frequency":[3] 1,
  create: "dom.successive_dialog_time_limit": 0,
```

Goal: Update all current Firefox installs to a current version and apply the custom settings using enterprise capabilities.  Establish process to manage Firefox for all future installs and updates.  Don't break the app.

Problem:  These changes can be easily applied individually via about:config.  They are not part of the GPO templates and its not clear how to add them or if it can be done.  Applying them via policies.json doesn't seem to work either.

On a representative test machine, a directory called \distribution has been created in the same directory as the firefox.exe [standard install, no hanky panky].  The file policies.json exists in the \distribution directory:

```
{
    "policies": {
      "Homepage": {
        "StartPage": "homepage",
        "URL": "https://www.google.com/"
      },
      "NewTabPage": true,
      "DontCheckDefaultBrowser": true,
      "Preferences": {
          "browser.cache.disk.enable":true,
          "dom.popup_maximum": -1,
          "dom.successive_dialog_time_limit": 0,
          "browser.cache.check_doc_frequency":1
        }
    }
  }
```

[about:policies results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJp0M.png)

This image shows the results of about:policies.  The other settings, used to validate that the policies are working, get applied.

The results from about:config show that the three preferences that I need to affect, have not changed:

```
dom.popup_maximum;20
browser.cache.check_doc_frequency;3
and dom.successive_dialog_time_limit does not get created.
```

I believe that these are old preference options.  But I also believe that if I can make the changes manually and achieve the desired results, there must be a method to accomplish it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way to change preferences is to use a javascript file that you add to the source code in browser/defaults/preferences where you specify each preference individually.

See [here](https://mike.kaply.com/2012/03/15/customizing-firefox-default-preference-files/) for more information.